# Filtering product name(from products sheet) in order sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have products sheet in excel workbook but when i add new order line in order sheet in same workbook, i want to filter products when i press keys to write product name.

Is there any way to show filtered product names in order sheet?

For example: When I write "Chee", it should filter the column and show relevant cells under it:

```
Chee
-----------
Cheese Dutch
Cheese French
Cheeseburger
Cheetos
```

Comment: Looks like you're in need of a database! ;)

Comment: I'm not Catholic, but St. Isidore protect us from another "Excel Database" ... I strongly suggest adopting a philosophy of "the right tool for the job."

Comment: Do you think this is difficult thing and can't be in excel ? Do you know excel row limit? it is always increasing, why? Why do people need to have more line than 64000? Why has it 1,048,576 row limit now? Do you still think it isn't like db? It is searching in other workbook(databases)'s sheet(Table). It is returning a vector or scalar value. And you can bind excel file as a db. Think again, it is trying to be db something like more functional classical db and more compact isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you download `AutoCompleteDataValidation(SortOf)2.xls` from https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/auto-complete/auto-complete-single-list change an entry in `Column A` of `Sheet Lists` to 'Chee', overwrite some entries in `Column B` of the same Sheet with Cheese Dutch, Cheese French, Cheeseburger, Cheetos and then see how you get on with entering data in `Sheet Single B2`. You might want to turn off Autocomplete. You should be able to enter 'Chee' or click the down arrow to find 'Chee' and either way then click again to pick the right detail.